Rotation matrix compatible with azimuth AND elevation rotation
After several days on Google, I'm stuck.
I define a square with center along x-axis (2 points on xz plane & 2 on xy plane). Aperture of alpha for example.
So, we have 4 points on cartesian coordinates XYZ: C = cos(alpha) & S = sin(alpha)



Point number
X
Y
Z
Azimuth
Elevation




1
C
S
0
alpha
0


2
C
0
-S
0
-alpha


3
C
-S
0
-alpha
0


4
C
0
S
0
alpha



Now, what I wish is to rotate on azimuth AZ (xy plane) AND on elevation EL (xz plane) keeping my square perpendicular to this new direction.
Naively, I tried:
1) Rotation of (-EL) on y-axis => square center axis always on xz plane with desired elevation.
2) Rotation of AZ on z-axis => square center axis with desired azimuth.
3) Test on 4 rotated points (with same numeration as above)




Point number
Azimuth
Elevation




1
alpha + AZ
EL


2
AZ
-alpha + EL


3
-alpha + AZ
EL


4
AZ
alpha + EL



For me, reasoning is good but, of course (ask question, need help!), it doesn't work.
Without success too, I read some articles and find some interactive about Euler angles
http://exoplanetes.esep.pro/esep_outils/nanosat/sequences-euler-313-312/Sequences-d-Euler.html
https://phyanim.sciences.univ-nantes.fr/Meca/Cinematique/euler1.php
I also try to understand using of quaternion but it's too abstract for me!
It seems these 3 methods are usable. So, my greatest expectation is to know where is the error in reasoning?
